# How to create a PayPal encrypted button for custom shopping cart?

Tags: paypal

I cannot figure this out, and neither can the people on some developers forums I have posted to.
The link below has example code to upload the contents of a custom shopping cart to PayPal.  It works great, but it comes with a caveat.  On the page, right above the code sample, is this important message:
"Important: The example button code shown below is unencrypted for illustrative purposes only. In reality, you must always use encrypted or hosted buttons in your web pages to prevent malicious users from tampering with the code. See Securing Your PayPal Payments Standard Buttons for instructions."
So my questions is this: how to I create an encrypted or hosted button to do the upload.  I have tried, but PayPal won't let me create a button unless I enter the price of the purchase.  Duh! It is a shopping cart.  The price is always different. 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/

Comment: I suspect you have to encrypt it yourself, by which they really mean 'encrypt and sign'. There's a whole rigmarole of registering your public key and certificate with them, and getting theirs, then to encrypt with their public key and sign with your own private key, then only they can decrypt, and they can verify your signature.

Answer (score 1):

Please view this documentation for assistance.

This is the API reference for buttons

[PayPal Button Manager API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/NVP/ButtonMgrOverview/)

This is documentation about securing the buttons that is also linked on the cart upload page.

[Securing Your PayPal Payments Standard Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/)